# Jmeter script does not open

Tags: jmeter

I have been running JMeter script for a couple of months. My JMeter GUI started freezing for the last couple of days, so I removed the old JMeter and installed it again. Now when I try to open my scripts I get this error (image below). The scripts that I am trying to open are recorded script. I am not able to understand the error message.

[image]

Comment: This is a missing jar exception.

Comment: Add JSON PATH Extractor plugin to lib/ext folder of JMeter.

Comment: @Naveen- i tried after installing the plugin but keep getting the same error.

Comment: any feedback on answer ? thx

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all missing plugins used by your script.

Either use Plugins Manager or old version :

- https://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/

Restart JMeter after that.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is due to missing [JSON Path Extractor plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/) so you need to get it back. The easiest way to restore the plugin and keep it up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/)

1. [Install JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager). Don't forget to restart JMeter after placing the Plugins Manager .jar file to JMeter's "lib/ext" folder
2. From JMeter's main menu select `Options -> Plugins Manager`
3. Switch to the `Available` tab
4. Locate `JSON Plugins`
5. Click `Apply Changes and Restart JMeter` button

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager]